# Increase root disc space and gain access to existing hard drives

Tags: partition, hard-disk, root-filesystem

I have an issue on my CentOS machine with hard drive space on root.

df -h returns

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                126G  352M  126G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                126G   59M  126G   1% /run
tmpfs                126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root   50G   50G  255M 100% /
/dev/mapper/cl-home  898G  887G   11G  99% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2       976M  360M  550M  40% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1       599M  7.3M  592M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                 26G   72K   26G   1% /run/user/1001
```

However a screenshot of the Disks application shows I have additional (unmounted?) drives:
[image]

When I try to format the 8.0 TB Hard Disk in an attempt to mount it CentOS warns me that all data on the volume will be lost - I do not want to lose any of the files on my system so am unsure about this.

How do I increase the size of root and how can I get access to the 1TB and 8TB storage shown in the Disk GUI without any risk of losing files?

EDIT:
vgs returns:

```
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  cl   1   3   0 wz--n- 952.28g    0
```

pvs returns:

```
  PV             VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1p3 cl lvm2 a--  952.28g    0
```

fdisk -l returns:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6C8024F1-6066-44CF-955B-F9869E79A4A9

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1230847    1228800   600M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1230848    3327999    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 3328000 2000408575 1997080576 952.3G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sda: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 08429B71-E4F8-4794-9128-733FDAD3C5EF

Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048     1230847     1228800  600M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1230848     3327999     2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3328000 15628052479 15624724480  7.3T Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-swap: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-home: 898.3 GiB, 964522147840 bytes, 1883832320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: what are the results of `vgs` and `pvs`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question to include the results of vgs and pvs.

Comment: Tom, your 1TB disk is used for `root` and `home` filesystems. About 8TB maybe `fdisk -l` can give you a answer.

Comment: Tom, check line which start with `/dev/sda3` Your disk is already partitioned and this is the reason for the error. However this specific partition have PV and I do not know if you have any info there

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have updated my question again with fdisk -l. Perhaps I should be moving the /home/ filesystem to the 8TB disk or I should increase the amount of space allocated to /root/ above 50GB. How do I check /dev/sda3 ? df -h does not show it unfortunately

Comment: sda3 is marked as Physical Volume (part of LVM). But you should remember why/how this volume is created and do you have any info there. If you do not have you can extend the VG with this amount and use it.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am fairly sure that I have not used the 8TB HDD. My machine has a 8TB HDD and a 1TB SSD. There is no way to check to be sure?

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments it seems you have another PV which (**if no information there**) you can add to the VG:

```
vgextend cl /dev/sda3
```

After this you can extend the LVs:

```
lvextend -L+2GB /dev/mapper/cl-root
```

(this add 2GB to `root` filesystem)

and then extend `root` filesystem. The command depend of the filesystem you use